# Is there a way to convert a string array to a set? I am trying to use the symmetricDifference function found in the set class but it will not work

Tags: arrays, swift, set

```
let chArr: [Character] = ["a","b","c","d","f"]

let stringList = String(describing: chArr)
  
let set1: Set = Set([stringList])
    
let lowerAlp = ["a", "b","c","d","e","f"]


let diff = set1.symmetricDifference(lowerAlp)


print(diff)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing getting in your way is using `let stringList = String(describing: chArr)`, which is giving you a string that reads `"["a", "b", "c", "d", "f"]"` -- in other words, not actually an `Array`, but rather a single string.

I'm unclear on whether you want to start with an `Array` of `Character` or `String`, but assuming you're truly starting with `[Character]` like in your example code, and you want to end up with `Set<String>`, you could do:

```
let chArr: [Character] = ["a","b","c","d","f"]
let stringList = Set(chArr.map { String($0) })
let lowerAlp = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
let diff = stringList.symmetricDifference(lowerAlp)
print(diff)
```

If you're starting with `[String]`, it would be:

```
let stringList = Set(["a","b","c","d","f"])
let lowerAlp = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
let diff = stringList.symmetricDifference(lowerAlp)
print(diff)
```

Comment: why not simply `let diff = Set("abcdf").symmetricDifference("abcdef")`?

Comment: Btw no need to map the characters to string. Better to explicitly set `lowerAlp` as `[Character]` as well

Comment: @LeoDabus totally agree -- I figured there must be *some* reason for the initial constraints, but the question certainly doesn't make it totally clear what the input requirements are.